# How to interpret TFLite output tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-api, tensorflow-lite, softmax

I am executing a TFLite model on python in order to make predictions based on input data. The model has been trained on AutoML-Google-API, then I downloaded its TFLite model. I used tf.lite.Interpreter to load the model and run an inference as follows

```
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details();print(input_details )
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details();print(output_details )
//...preparing input_data
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index']);print(output_data )
```

The results are as follows:

```
input_details: 
[{'name': 'image',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3]),
  'dtype': numpy.uint8,
  'quantization': (0.007874015718698502, 128)}]
output_details: 
[{'name': 'scores',
  'index': 173,
  'shape': array([ 1, 10]),
  'dtype': numpy.uint8,
  'quantization': (0.00390625, 0)}]
output_data : 
array([[ 34, 100,  67,  14,  15,  24,  21,  18,  25,  37]], dtype=uint8)
```

The `output_data` has some integer numbers, is it true to say that "the index of its largest number corresponds to the predicted label", and how can I convert those numbers to probability?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) to convert the numbers into probability distribution and [argmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax) to get the index of the label with the largest probability.

So something like this:

```
output_probs = tf.math.softmax(output_data)
pred_label = tf.math.argmax(output_probs)
```

Comment: Thank you. For softmax output, the summation of probs equals to 1. How about the summation of 'output_data'? When I add up the values of output_data, based on the given input image,  it gives different values. In the above example, the summation is (34+100+67+...=355), but for other samples, I got different values like 345, 370, ... Is it normal?

Comment: Yes that seems normal, as the direct output of the network are just the weights of your output layer. Normal procedure with classifiers such as yours is to use softmax and argmax to get the index of the predicted label.